# Undefined index even if a radio button is pressed before clicking submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am new to php. And writing this code where it will take data from mysql and show it in drop down. Once selected and clicked submit it will then show its child in other drop down. At the last node when the user clicks on any option and press submit it will show options to insert into database with the selected product id. I have 3 parent i.e electronics, vehicles, furniture. All my code works perfectly fine for electronics but shows error in rest of the nodes. It shows undefined index even if i have pressed the radio button before. The radio button does not pass the value once clicked submit.

I am using php7, Phpmyadmin.

```
        //calling parentids - - - - - - - - - - >
        $sql = "CALL `callcatname`()";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        ?>
     <select name="select" style="width: 100px;"> 
     <?php
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<option value=".$row["catname"].">".$row["catname"]."</option>";
        }
        } 
        $result->free();
        $conn->close;
        ?>
     <!-- calling parent id doneee (DB inactive) -->
     <!-- Calling categories -->
     <br>
     <div></div>
     <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
  </form>
  <?php 
     if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
     ?>
  <table border=1>
     <th style="width:60px ">Select</th>
     <th>Name </th>
     <form action="index.php" method="Post">
        <?php
           $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username,$password,$database);
           $temp = $_POST["select"];
           setcookie("temp",$temp);
           $sql = "Call callchildren1('$temp')";
           $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
           while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
           echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' value='".$row["ProdName"]."' name='".$temp."'></td><td>".$row["ProdName"]."</td></tr>";
           }
           $conn->close();
           $result->free();
           echo"<td><input type='Submit' name='Submit1' value='Submit'></td>";
           }
           ?>
  </table>
  </form>
  <!-- calling categories doneee (DB inactive) -->
  <!-- calling 3 level children -->
  <?php
     if(isset($_POST["Submit1"])){
     $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username,$password,$database);
     $temp = $_COOKIE["temp"];
     $cat = $_POST[$temp];
     Echo "<br><br>The products in <strong>".$temp."(".$cat.")</strong> are: <br><br> ";
     $sql = "Call callchildren1('$cat')";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
     ?>
  <form action="index.php" method="POST">
     <table border=1>
        <th style="width:80px">Select</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <?php
           while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
           echo "<tr>
           <td><input type='radio' value='".$row["ProdName"]."' name='".$cat."'></td><td >".$row["ProdName"]."</td></tr>";
           setcookie("cat",$cat);
           }
           echo "<td style='padding-left:10px'><input type='submit' name='insert' value='Insert'></td>";
           // echo "<td style='padding-left:20px'><input type='submit' name='view' value='View'></td> </table>";
           $result->free();
           $conn->close();
           //setcookie('temp',"",time() -3000); 
           }
           ?>
  </form>
  </table>
  <?php
     $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username,$password,$database);
     if(isset($_POST["view"])){
     $cat1 = $_COOKIE["cat"];
     $sql = "Call callchildren1($cat1)";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
     echo $_POST[$cat1];;
     }
     ?>
  <?php
     $cat1 = $_COOKIE["cat"]; 

     if(isset($_POST["insert"])){

     $temp = $_POST[$cat1];
     echo"Product name: <input type='text' name='pname'> Product Category: <input type='text' name='pname' value='".$_POST[$cat1]."' disabled> <br><br> Product description:<input type='text' name='pname'> Product price:<input type='number' name='pname'>" ;
     echo"<br><br>Product image: <input type ='file' value='Upload Image' id='fileName' accept='.jpg' onchange='validateFileType'><br><br><input type='submit'>";

     }

     ?>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Like in this screenshot the SLR and DSLR are 3 level children of electronics. and if i press submit it should show a list of text box with the selected option

[image: Like in this screenshot the SLR and DSLR are 3 level children of electronics. and if i press submit it should show a list of text box with the selected option]

[image]

even if i select a radio button and press submit it shows this error

[image: even if i select a radio button and press submit it shows this error]

I expect a result where the selected option should be shown in the textbox.

Comment: ```Product Category:
 <input type='text' name='pname' value='".$_POST[$cat1]."' disabled>``` disabledvalue will not submit on form

Comment: @sarvonks thank you for the reply. But I am not submitting the disabled form. My error is that once i click the radio button. It does not display the selected value in disabled input box